# How to show thumbnails of posts in a category at the end of a single post?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, categories

I posted this yesterday but then when I signed up after I couldn't see the question anymore, so apologies if it is now on here twice!

I'm trying to show a grid of thumbnails at the end of a single page. I have the grid working fine on my "work" page which is a category page.  They are displayed as a thumbnail grid using the code below. And you can see on the site [Here](https://nathanspence.com/work/).

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<div class="grid work thumb-wrap clearfix">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
                    

        <a class="thumb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img src="http://www.nathanspence.com/wp-content/uploads/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true); ?>"/>
            <div class="post-excerpt">
                <h2><?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?></h2>
                <div class="sub-title"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'project-name', true); ?></div>
            </div>      
        </a>

                    
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

</div><!--end of "thumb-wrap"-->

<div class="push"></div>
    
</div><!--end of "page-wrap"--> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I want to duplicate this at the end of each single post. [Here](https://nathanspence.com/work/pete-mizell/).

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="page-content">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 

<article class="work post-content ready-to-column clearfix">
                
    <header class="post-header column-left">
        <h1><?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?></h1>
        <h2><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'project-name', true); ?></h2>
        <div class="project-info"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'project-info', true); ?></div>                   
    </header>
    
    <div class="column-right">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    
        

    
    
    
    </div><!---end of "right-column flex-column"--->

            
</article>
    
<?php endwhile; else: ?>    
<p>Sorry, this post does not exist</p>
<?php endif; ?>
    
    <div class="grid work thumb-wrap clearfix">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
                    

        <a class="thumb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img src="http://www.nathanspence.com/wp-content/uploads/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true); ?>"/>
            <div class="post-excerpt">
                <h2><?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?></h2>
                <div class="sub-title"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'project-name', true); ?></div>
            </div>      
        </a>

                    
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

</div><!--end of "thumb-wrap"-->

<div class="push"></div>
    
</div><!--end of "page-wrap"--> 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I want to have this grid show at the end of a single post. I have tried just pasting the same loop in but as you can see, simply pasting it in just shows the current posts thumbnail. Any idea how I can do this? I'm a designer who is just learning to be able to maintain my own site, so I'm a bit lost reading about loops etc. Thanks!

Edit: So to make it clearer. How do I get this code below to output all posts in that category at the end of the single post?

```
<a class="thumb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img src="http://www.nathanspence.com/wp-content/uploads/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true); ?>"/>
            <div class="post-excerpt">
                <h2><?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?></h2>
                <div class="sub-title"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'project-name', true); ?></div>
            </div>      
        </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this where you want all post

```
<?php 
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>
 
<?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
 
<ul>
 
    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->
 
</ul>
 
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
 
<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Where would this go in the context of my current code? I'm a bit lost now. If you could show me where to put this and what to take out of my current code that would be a massive help! :)

Comment: @NathanSpence above code will come before `<?php get_footer(); ?>` line. you just need to fix bit of design

Comment: ok. And where does this code for the grid thumbnails fit in that? ```<a class="thumb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
   <img src="http://www.nathanspence.com/wp-content/uploads/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true); ?>"/>
   <div class="post-excerpt">
    <h2><?php echo get_the_title($ID); ?></h2>
    <div class="sub-title"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'project-name', true); ?></div>
   </div>  
  </a>```

Comment: @NathanSpence you can replace `<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>` code with yours.

Comment: Yup I did that and removed the UL tags just because I didn't put the items as a list. Maybe they should be but it works. Thanks!